# Dismiss dialog and close activity in single back press

Tags: android

I am showing dialog on activity start with:

```
mDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

When user press the back button, its first dismiss the dialog and then on again press on back button it close the activity. I want to do this in single back press, close the dialog and close activity.
I have tried wit the following code also:

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            // AppDialogUtils.mDialog.setCancelable(true);
            // AppDialogUtils.mDialog.dismiss();
            mActivity.finish();
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Answer (score 22):

Set a `mDialog.setOnCancelListener(listener)` and close the `Activity` in that listener.

```
@Override
mDialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {

    public void onCancel(DialogInterface interface) {
        this.finish();            
    }
});
```

Alternatively you could use a `OnKeyListener` for your `Dialog`.

```
mDialog.setOnKeyListener(new Dialog.OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(DialogInterface interface, int keyCode,
                KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                this.finish();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `OnCancelListener`

```
alertDialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {

    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
        // finish activity             
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have set `mDialog.setCancelable(true)` then set

```
mDialog.setOnCancelListener {
                    this.finish()
                }
```

Note: This is the lambda function for the `setOnCancelListener`.

Answer (score -1):

this may works for you.

first I don't think this one works

```
mDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

you can use

```
dialog.setCancelable(false);
```

now its works as you wanted.

Answer (score -1):

if your dialog is open then

```
dialog.dismiss();
```

this will make dismiss your dialog and if you want to press back then use this line

```
@Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
 super.onBackPressed();
   finish();
 }
```

this will work for you

Answer (score -2):

Overload the activity's `onBackPressed()` event and dismiss the dialog and activity in the same function.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   dialog.dismiss();
   finish();
}
```

Comment: This is very bad solution, because you must keep `dialog` object in activity, also you can easily get NPE. Flagging as low quality.